How to fix XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE in android?
I am trying to run open XR hello demo in my android studio but facing difficulties to fix some paths.
This command i used to build:
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug 
-DANDROID=ON 
-DJAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
-DANDROID_NDK=$ANDROID_NDK 
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake 
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-26 
-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON 
-DHIDAPI_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/hidapi 
-Dbluetooth_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/bluetooth/bluetooth.h 
-DOPENHMD_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openhmd
-DXRT_FEATURE_STEAMVR_PLUGIN=OFF 
-G "Unix Makefiles"

I am able to build it successfully and then getting error in logcat with message "XrResult failure [XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE]"
Here is full log:
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Could access neither the installable nor system runtime broker.
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Error [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : RuntimeManifestFile::FindManifestFiles - failed to determine active runtime file path for this environment
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Error [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : RuntimeInterface::LoadRuntimes - unknown error
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Error [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : RuntimeInterface::LoadRuntimes - failed to load a runtime
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Error [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Failed to find default runtime with RuntimeInterface::LoadRuntime()
OpenXR-Loader org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E Error [GENERAL | xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties | OpenXR-Loader] : Failed querying extension properties
hello_xr org…onos.openxr.hello_xr.opengles E [07:34:15.492][Error ] XrResult failure [XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE]
Origin: xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(layerName, 0, &instanceExtensionCount, nullptr)
Source: /home/dk/Ravi/OpenXrDemos/OpenXR-SDK-Source/src/tests/hello_xr/openxr_program.cpp:133

Please help how can i fix this error ?
